# Problems Facebook authentication in Asp.Net MVC 3 with jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-mobile

this is my first post so thanks all for your help :)

I have an asp.net mvc 3 web application in which i added an Area with jquery mobile functionalities.
I add facebook login using libraries Facebook, Facebook.Web and Facebook.Web.Mvc ver 5.4.1.0.
I have no problem in the web site scope, so if i logon facebook and then navigate:

```
http://localhost:2508/Home

FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated() //return true
```

But if navigate the area with jquery mobile app:

```
http://localhost:2508/MobileApp/Home

FacebookWebContext.Current.IsAuthenticated() //return false
```

I hope that all understood me

Any suggestions?

This is html of my _Layout page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/MobileApp.min.css")" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css")" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/CustomMobileInit.js")"></script>
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js")"></script>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="fb-root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
                FB.init({ appId: '@Facebook.FacebookApplication.Current.AppId', channelURL: '@Request.Url.Scheme://@Request.Url.Authority@Url.Content("~/fbchannel.ashx")', cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) { window.location.reload(); });
                FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) { window.location.reload(); });
            };

            (function(d){
                var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
                js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
                js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
                d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
            }(document));
        </script>

        <div data-role="page" id="MainPage" data-theme="a">

            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h3>
                    My Mobile App
                </h3>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">

                @RenderBody()

            </div>

            <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
                @{ dynamic me = Helpers.Utilities.FBGet("/me"); }
                @if (me != null)
                {
                    <h3>
                        @me.name
                    </h3>
                }
                else
                {
                    <h3>
                        Utente sconosciuto
                    </h3>
                }
            </div>

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and there are some pages that implement this _Layout.
I discovered that the issue appear when ajax is enabled. If disabled the oAuth work correctly but i left page transitions.

Comment: it unlikely that you'll get an answer to this without sharing more code... what's the minumum change you can make to the standard project template in order to reproduce this problem?